# Need help to make own coordinate system (classic, center of UIView is 0,0)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiview

I need to create my own coordinate system in UIView, where 0,0 is center of UIView. But I don't know ho to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *view = /*...*/;
CGContextRef ctx = /*...*/;

/* Shift center from UL corner to mid-x, mid-y. */
CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
CGFloat hx = bounds.size.width / 2.0;
CGFloat hy = bounds.size.height / 2.0;
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, hx, hy);

/* y still increases down, and x to the right. */
/* if you want y to increase up, then flip y: */
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0/*sx*/, -1.0/*sy*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, (0,0) is in the upper left corner of the view. To move this point to the view's center, modify its bounds:

```
CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;
self.bounds = CGRectMake(-width/2.0, -height/2.0, width, height);
```

Make sure to repeat this calculation whenever the size of the view changes.